# Basic conditional probability problem

Tags: conditional-probability

I found this problem in the Sheldon Ross book:

In a certain community, 36 percent of the families
own a dog and 22 percent of the families that own
a dog also own a cat. In addition, 30 percent of the
families own a cat. What is

(a) the probability that a randomly selected family
owns both a dog and a cat?

(b) the conditional probability that a randomly
selected family owns a dog given that it owns
a cat?

The answer to a) is given as $$P(D\cap C) = P(C\vert D)P(D)$$

This is very non-intuitive to me as I can't understand why $$P(D\cap C) \not =  P(C \vert D) \not = P(D \vert C)$$

Answer (score 1):

You are someone who always bring an umbrella whenever it rains, also, sometimes you might bring an umbrella even when it is not raining.

Let $D$ be the event that it rains, and $C$ is the event that you bring an umbrella.

$$P(C|D)=1$$

However, it doesn't means that it rains all the time, $P(C \cap D)<1$.

Also, it is unlikely that whenever you bring an umbrella, it brings rain. $P(D|C)<1$.